# Not-Colorful Screen

Tags: screen, colors

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and my screen isn't colorful. I thought that I would go to the Color section in the settings app to choose a more colorful color profile, but apparently there is no such thing in Ubuntu. I also found sites online saying that I should "select my screen and calibrate it" but there is no calibrate button anywhere in the color section.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean it's not colorful? The display is in grayscale?

Comment: @Nmath It's not grayscale but it's less "saturated" than my other laptops. This can usually be fixed on other operating systems by changing the color profile but there is no way to change or add them on Ubuntu.